# How to configure Jenkins to send a notification email when a Slave goes offline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, slave, nightly-build

How to configure Jenkins to send a notification email when a Slave goes offline?
I have a Windows Server in the Cloud.
In there is a Jenkins Slave running that runs a nightly build, but sometimes the Slave goes offline and I need to know when it goes offline.
How can I configure to Jenkins send me a email notification in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the slave configuration, there's an option "Notify when Node online status changes". If you check it, it will allow you to enter email addresses to be notified when the slave comes online/goes offline.

Comment: i dont find this option.
Can you explain where can I find this option?
My Jenkins version is 1.480.2.

Comment: I have version 1.504. You'll have to upgrade to get that option.

Comment: Please see better answer below; this is not available without installation of "mail watcher" plugin.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff your answer is accepted, but probably you should add Stephen Ash's addition about Mail watcher

Answer (score 32):

The setting that Lars mentions does not seem to come with a default Jenkins installation (v1.514). I see it with the [Mail watcher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Watcher+Plugin)